# Nested for loop in R with magic_for function

Tags: r, nested-loops

List of Datasets that I am using:-
1. .nc files of climate data 
2. List of cities (53) with latitude and longitude for retrieving data from .nc file
3. Working code:-
I have been successful in retrieving data for 53 cities by using magic_for loop.So currently I am able to save the path of a .nc file and retrieve the daily values of variables such as tasmin, tasmax, pr and tas by using a magic_for function. Each of these files has data for a period from 2006-2100 for single variable.
4. Problem:-
Now for a model where I have 19 .nc files (5 years each) unlike the previous 1 file (95 years). Hence I want to use the working program as mentioned above to run nineteen times. 
5. Code:-
**Working:**

```
tasfilepath<-paste0("path.nc")
model1<-nc_open(tasfilepath)
lonmodel1<-ncvar_get(model1, varid = 'lon')
latmodel1<-ncvar_get(model1, varid = 'lat')
timemodel1<-nc.get.time.series(model1, v="tasmin", time.dim.name = "time")
input<-read.xlsx(file = "cities_1.xlsx", sheetName = "Sheet1")
i<-length(col(input[1]))
magic_for(print1, silent = TRUE)
for (j in 1:i)
{
  alat<-which.min(abs(latmodel1-input[j,2]))
  alon<-which.min(abs(lonmodel1-input[j,3]))
  temp<-nc.get.var.subset.by.axes(model1, "tasmin", axis.indices = list(X=alon, Y=alat))
print1(temp) 
}
df0<-magic_result_as_dataframe()
```

**Not working:**

```
input0<-read.xlsx(file = "sheet with path addresses of .nc files.xlsx")
    i0<-length(col(input0[1]))
    magic_for(print2, silent = TRUE)
    for(k in 1:i0)
    {
        tasfilepath<-paste0(input0[k,2])
        model1<-nc_open(tasfilepath)
        lonmodel1<-ncvar_get(model1, varid = 'lon')
        latmodel1<-ncvar_get(model1, varid = 'lat')
        timemodel1<-nc.get.time.series(model1, v="tasmin", time.dim.name = "time")
        input<-read.xlsx(file = "cities_1.xlsx", sheetName = "Sheet1")
        i<-length(col(input[1]))
        magic_for(print1, silent = TRUE)
        for (j in 1:i)
          {
            alat<-which.min(abs(latmodel1-input[j,2]))
            alon<-which.min(abs(lonmodel1-input[j,3]))
            temp<-nc.get.var.subset.by.axes(model1, "tasmin", axis.indices = list(X=alon, Y=alat))
            print1(temp)
        }
        df0<-magic_result_as_dataframe()
        print2(df0)
    }
    df1<-magic_result_as_dataframe()
```

Error - Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  :arguments imply differing number of rows: 53, 19
Alternatives:
Even if I could create 19 dataframes and bind them together my problem will be solved.
Regards

Comment: This is a lot to process for 8:22. Have you tried adding a `browser()` call before the suspected offending line and examining the result?

Comment: Hi Roman, I haven't used the browser (). Would it be possible for you to share a link or explain further. Anyway I am reading the r documentation on it.

Comment: There's plenty of resources to learn about debugging in R. Here's one: https://adv-r.hadley.nz/debugging.html#browser